# How to stop time subtraction on 00:00:00 in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using query which is subtracting time. Problem is, when it reaches to  00:00:00 it doesn't stop subtracting and it start going in negative like `- 00:20:00`

```
Sale::where('date','=',$current->toDateString())
      ->where('time','<=',$current->toTimeString())
      ->update(['duration' => DB::raw('DATE_SUB(duration, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)')]);
```

I want to stop it on `00:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```php
Sale::where('date', $current->toDateString())
    ->where('time', '<=', $current->toTimeString())
    ->update([
        'duration' => DB::raw('GREATEST(DATE_SUB(duration, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), TIME(0))')
    ]);
```

This will restrict the lowest possible time value to 00:00:00 by adding the [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html) MySQL function.